# Azure AD graph API to filter users with onPremisesExtensionAttributes [extensionAttribute6]

Tags: filter, graph, azure-active-directory

I need to filter users with the onPremisesExtensionAttributes [extensionAttribute6]  is there a graph API call for it?

Comment: Refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties), it said 'the individual extension attributes are neither selectable nor filterable'.

Comment: Hi, if my answer is helpful, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like they've updated the BETA Graph API so that extension attributes (onPremisesExtensionAttributes) are now filterable.

Try the below in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).  You'll need to change the extensionAttribute1 eq 'Employee' part to a query that will actually work in your active directory environment.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$count=true&$filter=onPremisesExtensionAttributes/extensionAttribute1 eq 'Employee'&$orderBy=displayName&$select=displayName,mail,onPremisesExtensionAttributes

Please note that this is the BETA Graph API so I guess that means Microsoft hasn't finalized it, so it might change or never get fully released.

EDIT:  I also just learned that if you're using this filter via the Graph API, you must add the following header or you'll an error:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual");
```

The Graph Explorer has this header by default, I guess.

Here's where I found this answer:  [Get Extended Properties on User using Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925030/get-extended-properties-on-user-using-microsoft-graph)

Here's the error I was getting:
Property 'extensionAttribute1' does not exist as a declared property or extension property.

Answer (score 2):

As @Tinywa suggested in the comment:

> onPremisesExtensionAttributes contains extensionAttributes 1-15 for
> the user. Note that the individual extension attributes are neither
> selectable nor **filterable**.

You can get all the results first and use your own code logic to filter them.

Or you can consider using [extensionProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) as a workaround. Create the `extensionProperty` and assign value for the users, and then query users with filtering with this `extensionProperty`. For detailed steps to create `extensionProperty` and assign value for users, you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65919881/create-user-custom-attribute-for-whole-b2c-instance-via-graph-api-or-graph-sdk?answertab=votes#tab-top).